# Does OpenID Connect have something similar to the SAML 2.0 allowCreate flag?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We're building an OIDC OP for a number of applications and would like some applications to specify whether it is a returning user flow or whether a new user could be registered.

This can be done in SAML 2.0 using the allowCreate flag on the web browser SSO profile.

Is there a similar concept in OpenID Connect? I've looked through the spec, and can't see anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OpenId Connect is built on top of the OAuth2 framework protocol.
OAuth2 supports [access token scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3).

We can imagine that `allowCreate` could be a scope passed by the client to the authorization server.
Then, the authorization server can verify the client or the resource owner (or both depending on your policy) is allowed to use that scope. If yes, an access token is issued and the client will be able to create resources on the resource server.